# Find largest number (C) - Code not working

Tags: c

I need the user to enter three numbers and my program to display the largest of these numbers. I can't seem to figure out the problem. The result I get is 
"The greatest number is 0.000"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

double n1, n2, n3;

printf("Enter your three numbers: ");
scanf("%1f %1f, %1f", &n1, &n2, &n3);

if (n1>= n2 && n1>= n3)
    printf("The greatest number is %f", n1);

if (n2>=n1 && n2>= n3)
    printf("The greatest number is %f", n2);

if (n3>=n2 && n3>=n1)
    printf("The greatest number is %f", n3);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have enabled all warnings on your compiler. Many modern compilers can warn about invalid conversion specifiers.

Comment: To me, this `%1f` looks like a typo - the `1` should be an `l` - as in `long` - you're scanning doubles, and specifying floats.

Comment: Good first steps when debugging:  0) Enable compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors; 1) Start testing with hardcoded data instead of user input; 2) Verify that user input produces what you believe it produces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler knows!

```
$ gcc -Wall temp.c
temp.c:9:23: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
scanf("%1f %1f, %1f", &n1, &n2, &n3);
       ~~~            ^~~
       %1lf
temp.c:9:28: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
scanf("%1f %1f, %1f", &n1, &n2, &n3);
           ~~~             ^~~
           %1lf
temp.c:9:33: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
scanf("%1f %1f, %1f", &n1, &n2, &n3);
                ~~~             ^~~
                %1lf
3 warnings generated.
```

Comment: What compiler doesn't know is that specifying maximum field width with 1 is probably not what was intended. Maybe add note about  `%lf` vs `%1lf`.

Answer (score 2):

As Vorsprung mentioned you need a proper format for reading/displaying, so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    double n1, n2, n3;

    printf("Enter your three numbers: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf, %lf", &n1, &n2, &n3);

    if (n1>= n2 && n1>= n3)
            printf("The greatest number is %lf", n1);

    if (n2>=n1 && n2>= n3)
            printf("The greatest number is %lf", n2);

    if (n3>=n2 && n3>=n1)
            printf("The greatest number is %lf", n3);


    return 0;
}
```